# Google Cloud Platform for Mobile App Confusion

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-app-engine

I am new to android. I am confused about google cloud platform.My focus is on using android app for RESTful service.

Why do I need google cloud platform when I can use native android library to access RESTful web service like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429997/Sample-Implementation-of-Virgil-Dobjanschis-Rest-p).( I mean using JSON parsing with HTTPClient/Volley etc)

As far as I have understood that to implement google cloud service, I need an android client, a backend and others....( I m not sure). Why do I need this EXTRA stuff/coding when, as I said before, I can get RESTFul response with conventional way with sdk library.The implementation of [Mobile Solutions on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/how-to-build-mobile-app-with-app-engine-backend-tutorial/) is difficult and strenuous task.

What are the cases, when I HAVE to use google cloud platform, cant I do it other easy way?

Comment: You never HAVE to, you COULD if you need your own custom RESTful web service, as in the *server*-side and you probably SHOULD NOT if you just want to use an existing 3rd party RESTful webservice.

Answer (score 0):

As per zapl's comment, there really is no reason why you need to use Google Cloud Platform with Android. Nowhere in any of Google's docs does it mention that GCP is a requirement for an Android app. Cloud Platform is a service Google offers if you want to develop your own web applications or backends for mobile applications, but you are by no means locked into using this service.